# Select by location fails for some lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, line, overlapping-features, select-by-location

I have many line objects in a layer called *"line"* (pink). Further, I have line objects in a layer called *"Connection"* (blue). The lines in *"Connection"* are created by the tool "distance to the nearest hub (line to hub)".

Now I want to select all object in *"lines"* that connect with the lines from *"connection"*. I tried to use "Select by location" with the options "intersect" and "touch".

[image]

As a result, only about half of the lines are actually selected.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Just for clarification, in your second image, which line features are the selected ones? Is it just the light green-ish segment on the bottom left? I've tried recreating a similar output but didn't have any issues. Maybe you have to check if your `line` layer geometry is valid using the Check geometry tool?

Comment: Without having your data, we can just speculate: please share a sample of your data. Probably the lines form the two layers are not properly connected, see e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379655/88814 Try creating a (very small) buffer around your connections layer and repeat the select operation based on this.

Comment: Hello @babel. After checking your link I tried to extend my line a little bit by using the tool "extend lines". This works perfectly! Thanks for sharing the link! Apperently, in my case, "distance to the nearest hub (line to hub)" didn't create lines that really touched the target line for about half the cases. I don't know if that is a bug or maybe I did something wrong but anyways "extend lines" is a perfectly good workaround for problems like those.

Comment: Feel free to add this as an answer and accept it. Like this, it is easier to find than hidden here in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Babel that solved my problem:

"Without having your data, we can just speculate: please share a sample of your data. Probably the lines form the two layers are not properly connected, see e.g. gis.stackexchange.com/a/379655/88814 Try creating a (very small) buffer around your connections layer and repeat the select operation based on this."